CustomerInfo Entitlements returning empty - RevenueCat
I am migrating my iAP from SwiftyStoreKit to RevenueCat.
Following the documentation here: https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/migrating-to-revenuecat/swiftystorekit
I have the Subscriptions set up in the RevenueCat dashboard, and I am able to fetch and display to products.
When subscribing and activating the iAP for the user the following line is not called
if customerInfo?.entitlements.all["pro"]?.isActive == true || customerInfo?.entitlements.all["plus"]?.isActive == true

The subscription still goes through but the following returns and empty dictionary,
customerInfo?.entitlements.all

However the following is called showing the subscription
else {
     print("PURCHASE WITH: \(String(describing: transaction?.productIdentifier)) && \(String(describing: customerInfo?.activeSubscriptions.count))")

}

This is a Sandbox account and I am able to retrieve a receipt.
Why does customerInfo?.entitlements.all return empty and should I use customerInfo?.activeSubscriptions instead?
func subscribe() {
    
    print("Subscribe")
    
    print("Packages: \(String(describing: offering?.availablePackages))")
    
    print("iAP: \(iAPBundle)")

    impactFeedback.tapAction()
    
    //Revenue Cat
    
    if let packages = offering?.availablePackages {
        for p in packages {
            if p.storeProduct.productIdentifier == iAPBundle {
                
                print("Product ID is equal to IAP")

                Purchases.shared.purchase(package: p) { (transaction, customerInfo, error, userCancelled) in
                    
                    print("PURCHASED")

                    if userCancelled {
                        print("User cancelled purchase")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    if let err = error {
                        
                        if let error = error as? RevenueCat.ErrorCode {
                            print(error.errorCode)
                            print("ERROR: \(error.errorUserInfo)")

                            switch error {
                            case .purchaseNotAllowedError:
                                errorDescription = "Purchases not allowed on this device."
                                showError.toggle()
                                
                            case .purchaseInvalidError:
                                errorDescription = "Purchase invalid, check payment source."
                                
                            default: break
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                    } else if customerInfo?.entitlements.all["pro"]?.isActive == true || customerInfo?.entitlements.all["plus"]?.isActive == true {
                        print("Unlocked ") // THIS IS NOT READ
                        
                        // Update profile
                        print("Customer INFO: \(customerInfo!)")
                        
                        print("Entitlements: \(customerInfo!.entitlements.all)")
                        
                        if customerInfo?.entitlements.all["pro"]?.isActive == true {
                            subscribeToPro()
                        } else if  customerInfo?.entitlements.all["plus"]?.isActive == true {
                            subscribeToPlus()
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        print("PURCHASE WITH: \(String(describing: transaction)) && \(String(describing: customerInfo))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

